# How to delete multiple folders on VB.net

Tags: vb.net, directory

I have a code here but it doesn't work.

```
Dim folderExists As Boolean
    folderExists = My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())

    If folderExists = True Then
        Directory.Delete(folderExists & "\LOG", True)
        Directory.Delete(folderExists & "\logfile", True)

        MsgBox("Logs deleted", vbInformation)
    Else
        MsgBox("Logs doesn't exists!")
    End If
```

I want to delete folders and all the files inside them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim folder = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
Dim folderExists As Boolean = (My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(folder &"\LOG") And My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(folder &"\logfile"))
If folderExists Then
    Directory.Delete(folder & "\LOG", True)
    Directory.Delete(folder & "\logfile", True)
    MsgBox("Logs deleted", vbInformation)
Else
    MsgBox("Logs doesn't exists!")
End If
```

**Update** - The `folderExists` now checks for both folders. Credit to **@David Wilson** for pointing that out.

Comment: I tried it and it's deleting the folders which is i want, but when the folders doesnt exist, its giving me error. It should say Logs doesn't exists but it doesnt say that. @Farhan Anam

Comment: Error says "Could not find a part of the path"

Comment: Modify the boolean `folderExists` to check whether the folder you are deleting exists or not.

Comment: Also, are `LOG` and `logfile` files or folders?

Answer (score 1):

As an update to the answer fron @farhamanam -

```
Dim folder = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
Dim folderExists As Boolean = (My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(folder &"\LOG") and My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(folder &"\logfile"))
If folderExists Then
    Directory.Delete(folder & "\LOG", True)
    Directory.Delete(folder & "\logfile", True)
    MsgBox("Logs deleted", vbInformation)
Else
    MsgBox("Logs don't exist!")
End If
```

**If this works, give @farham the answer vote - Farham, you might want to edit your code to include this**